# Can't set UINavigationItem title programatically on initial load

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, navigationitem

I'm am performing a segue (via storyboard) from a TableViewController (embedded in a NavigationController) to another TableViewController. I.e Selecting a cell and presenting another TableView on which i would like to display the selected cell's text as the next views title.

I am achieving this however not 100% correctly. On the first initial selection of a cell the navigationItem title is not set. Only once i navigate back and then again forward through that same cell, is the title set.

The first snippet is my first viewController that I'm selecting a cell on where I am setting the destinationViewControllers variable with the selected cells title.

```
    var valueToPass:String?
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

        // Get Cell Label
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!;
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell!;

        valueToPass = currentCell.textLabel!.text
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "tripSegue") {

        // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
        let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! TripTableViewController
        // setting the view controllers property that will store the passed value
        viewController.passedValue = valueToPass
    }

}
```

The second snippet is from the destinationViewController setting the navigationItem title.

```
var passedValue: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.title = passedValue
}
```

Comment: Where does valurEoPass get set in the navcontroller

Comment: @DavidBerry I have edited the post to reflect your comment. See first snippet

Comment: I still don't see where you're setting valueToPass (probably in didSelect...)?

Comment: sorry, my edit failed. Please refer now. @DavidBerry

Comment: Trying move `self.navigationItem.title = passedValue` to somewhere before `viewDidLoad` of viewController 's lifecycle, etc, `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: @Wongzigii I have tried this previously and did it again now. Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `prepareForSegue` is called **before** `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. So the first time you select a row, `valueToPass` is nil. `prepareForSegue` is called while `valueToPass` is still nil and you pass it, then after you pass that, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called setting `valueToPass` to the desired value, which is what's passed the next time you select a row.

You need to do it all in `prepareForSegue`.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

if (segue.identifier == "tripSegue") {
       // Get Cell Label
       let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!;
       let currentCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell!;
       // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
       let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! TripTableViewController
       // setting the view controllers property that will store the passed value
       viewController.passedValue = currentCell.textLabel!.text

    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, do it in `didSelectRow...` and programmatically invoke the segue instead of automatically.

Comment: What would be considered best practice ?

Comment: @DavidBerry But I think he would still have to the exact same thing in `prepareForeSegue` whether the segue was performed programmatically or automatically triggered by row selection.

Comment: @Vince You're welcome glad I could help!! The only thing I would do differently is instead of getting the title from the cell's text label, I'd get it from the data source array that you used to populate the cell's label in the first place. Although I don't have a strong argument for why you shouldn't get it from the cell's label.